# AngularJS | Como definir um processo de inicialização para um controller?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Tenho um app cheio de Ajax que precisa obter dados via WebService quando a página carrega. Já inicializei via `ng-init` mas não sei como mandar o controller "carregar" e executar o bloco de código que recupera os dados. Quando eu insiro a função num `ng-click` e clico no elemento ela funciona, mas só assim.

Como faz para definir um processo de inicialização para um controller?

Comment: Coloque seu código para podermos ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Vi que basta eu chamar uma função do `$scope` na diretiva `ng-init` que ele faz o que eu estou esperando:

```
<div ng-init="init()">
    blah
</div>
```

No JavaScript:

```
//...
$scope.init = function() {} // ...
```

Isso faz com que o meu controller seja inicializado e execute a função `init`.

Referência: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150289/running-angularjs-initialization-code-when-view-is-loaded

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro crie um controlador no seu arquivo .js

```
app.controller('controlador', function($scope){

   $scope.funcao = function(){
       //algoritmo.
   };    
});
```

depois no seu html, declare esse controller

```
<div data-ng-controller="controlador">
    //Html
</div>
```

Comment: Poste uma explicação do que seu código faz e como faz.

Comment: como o usuário pediu somente para mostrar como inicializar um controller, só adicionei o código, achei que não precisava da explicação @Ricardo

Comment: RenanDegrandi postando uma explicação a resposta pode ser útil a mais membros além do autor da pergunta